# Is there a basis which spans the real numbers?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

> Is there a finite set of real numbers $S=\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n \}$ such that every real number can be written as a linear combination (with integer coefficients) of the elements of $S$? If no, is there a set $M= \{a_1, a_2, ... \}$ with a countably infinite number of elements, such that every real number can be written as a linear combination (with integer coefficients) of the elements of $M?$

I suspect the answer is no for both. However, if $S$ and/or $M$ exist, they must contain at least one transcendental number; a linear combination of only algebraic numbers should still be algebraic.

**Motivation:**

First, I solved a simpler problem. I wanted to see if we can span the integers with a finite basis containing any integers except $1$. The answer is yes. One such basis is $\{2, 3 \}$, because for any integer $n$, we have $n=n \cdot (3-2) = 3n - 2n=3n+2(-n).$

Next, I want to know if this can be done with rationals. I haven't worked on it, but I think I might have a shot at discovering the answer myself. However, I'm pretty sure that I can't solve the case for real numbers.

Comment: A linear combination with which coeffients? Over $\mathbb R$ you just need 1. With coefficients in $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb N$ you can't have a finite basis!

Comment: Over what ring do you want your basis? Obviously $\mathbb{R}$ is one-dimensional over itself. And it is infinite-dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is a one-dimensional vector space over itself, so of course there is a finite basis, consisting of just one (nonzero) real number. In order for the question to be interesting you need to specify what coefficients you're talking about. If you're considering $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, there is no finite basis.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I thought by definition linear combination meant integer coefficients. I'll add that into the question. Is it possible then to have a countably infinite basis that spans $\mathbb{R}$ using integer coefficients?

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ Please see my comment above

Comment: @Maffred Please see my comments above

Comment: When talking about a basis, you usually want every element (i.e. real number) to be representable using a _finite_ linear combination of basis elements. If your basis is countable, and your coefficient set is counrable, then the set of possible finite linear combinations is countable.

Comment: @Ovi: the answer to the question is no: the number of linear combinations of a countably infinite set with integer coefficients is countable, because the integers are countable.

Comment: @Arthur Hm okay, sorry for my ignorance here. Is there an elementary proof that shows that it's impossible to have any basis span $\mathbb{R}$ with only integer coefficients?

Comment: The reason $\{2,3\}$ spans $\mathbb{Z}$ is that $\gcd(2,3)=1$

Comment: There is the counting argument that my comment is based on. That disproves it immediately.

Comment: A basis spans a vector space. A vectors space is taken over a field, Integers aren't a field. You shouldn't call it a basis then. Maybe I make  mistake if so I apologize.

Comment: @marshalcraft You are probably right, but I'm not looking for a terribly rigorous answer (because I don't have knowledge of the required math myself). I just used this terminology that is probably incorrect but should be understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially addressed in the comments, but let me flesh it out (if only to move this question off the "unanswered" queue):

Your suspicion that this isn't possible is **correct**, and the easiest way to see this is via cardinality.

If $A$ is any countable set of reals and $C$ is any set of "allowed coefficients" (you use $\mathbb{Z}$, but $\mathbb{Q}$ would give the same answer, as would the set of algebraic numbers, or so on and so forth), then the set $$LinComb(A,C)=\{x: \exists c_1,..., c_n\in C, a_1,..., a_n\in A(x=c_1a_1+...+c_na_n)\}$$ is **countable**. Showing this is a good exercise; the key points are:

- The union of countably many countable sets is countable.
- The Cartesian product of two (hence, of finitely many) countable sets is countable.
- We can break $LinComb(A,C)$ into countably many "pieces" - namely, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have the set $LC_n(A,C)$ of reals which can be written as a linear combination of elements of $A$ using coefficients from $C$ **of length $n$**.

Now, what can you say about the cardinality of $LC_n(A,C)$, and how that determines the cardinality of $LinComb(A,C)$?

So $LinComb(A,C)$ is countable as long as $A$ and $C$ are. But [the reals are uncountable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument), so we'll never have $LinComb(A,C)=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Isn't your third bullet missing exactly the most important "piece", namely the linear combinations which, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists a non-zero coefficient $c_m$ with $m>n$?

Comment: @RonKaminsky No, it's not missing anything. Infinite sums are **not**  linear combinations (cf. the difference between "Hamel basis" and "Schauder basis").

Comment: Thanks, terminology always gets me! I have to wonder, then, why this is tagged "calculus".

Answer (score 1):

$1$ is a basis which spans the real numbers. Also a vectors space to have the said basis requires coefficients from a field.

Comment: I mentioned in the question that the coefficients must be integers

Comment: Here seems to be a related question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286017/what-would-happen-if-we-created-a-vector-space-over-an-integral-domain-ring